# error while calling the variable in a reader

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this piece of code:

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                count++;
                string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(Variables.buffering, reader.GetValue(0))));
                List<string> mystring = new List<string>();
                mystring.Add(Text);
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                {
                    string myText = new TextRange(mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentStart, mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.ContentEnd).Text;


                    var str = Regex.Replace(myText, @"( |\r?\n)\1+", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("hello")))));

                    string text = "s";
                    mainWindow.WriteSerial(text);
                    Console.WriteLine(Text);
                }
            }
            foreach (string element in mystring)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
```

why is that the mystring in my foreach loop has an error of:

```
Error   2   The name 'mystring' does not exist in the current context
```

*This is another problem encountered. Please neglect the previous one.

Comment: Please add the error message you are receiving.

Comment: there is no error. But it is not displaying the "Hello" string there

Comment: Well I am not sure what you're trying to do after you get the RowCount. Verify that your RowCount variable contains the correct number of rows, and you should be good.  Why do you call reader.GetValue(0)?? Also you should certainly not be trying to write to your window from your data access code.

Comment: One, why are you using a Reader to retrieve a single value.  Two did you step through in degbug?  What is the value of Text?  Is Convert.ToBoolean(Text) true?

Comment: yup it is true. I tested it without that rowcount command

Comment: How did you test and why did you remove the rowcount?  Did you see it step through the code block in if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text)) or not?

Comment: So now you change the whole question and on to the next problem.  You don't get that mystring does not exists in the current context?  You don't even have a basic understanding of .NET. Put the project on hold, get a book, and learn .NET.

Comment: I think I will not be needing the previous question anymore since I have already seek the appropriate answer to my problem. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the row count, you don't have to select on a specific column. Just do this:

```
using(SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString))
{
    sqliteCon.Open();
    using(SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeList", sqlliteCon))
    {
         createCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
         int RowCount = 0;
         RowCount = Convert.ToInt32(createCommand.ExecuteScalar());

    }
 }
```

*Note* Updated for proper use of `using` statements

Comment: the CommandType.Text; will generate an error. but if I remove it, then the reader will malfunction.

Comment: Try changing CommandType.Text to System.Data.CommandType.Text

Comment: the reader will still malfunction. It will not read anymore. I'll update my question for the rest of the code in reading the sqlite content

Comment: Why are you still calling ExecuteScalar()? Also, if you set the command text when you initialize the command, you don't have to set it again using the CommandText property.

Comment: edited the code and still the reader is not functioning. Please check my updated question for the code

Comment: Error 2 The name 'sqlliteCon' does not exist in the current context 
-this is the error in your revised code

Comment: **Check the spelling**

Comment: it generates lots of error. I will update my question for the screenshot

Comment: awh. wrong update. I did not notice that I have updated your answer. Sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48705/discussion-between-daniel-simpkins-and-iaskyou)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that

```
Convert.ToBoolean(Text)
```

Evaluates to false

Did you step through the code in debug?

And why a Reader for a single row:

```
RowCount = (Int32)createCommand.ExectueScalar.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah. I tested for it without that RowCount and peripherals. It will return true

Comment: Why would you remove RowCount if that is part of the code?  In debug did you see the line mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("hello"))))); executed?  You state no errors but not dispalying Hello?  Are you sure that code is called?  Are you seeing the Console.WriteLine(Text);?

Comment: wait. I'll try if my codes goes really in the while loop

Comment: Oh I get it, It will only execute once, I have a row number of 10, so apparently it will display the 10 boolean type, but in my case it only displays once

Comment: What do you expect from a count(*) other than a single row?

Comment: I thought that count(*) will count for the rows. I don't know if I try to read a content from the database that it will only scan for a single row then exited afterwards

Comment: Count of rows is a single number.  Count(*) is a single number.  10 is a single number.  100 is a single number.

Comment: How should I modify it? Sorry I am only a beginner in VSC# programming.

Comment: I get you are a beginner but learn to debug.  You posted to SO without even stepping through your code.  "SELECT column FROM EmployeeList".

Comment: yeah. I am also trying to debug it. :D this is just a piece of my project. I will try another approach if this one won't work